# java longest palindrome not working

Tags: java

I am working on a program that gives me longest palindrome:

Here is my code, this works fine for longest subsequence. But I want to do it in another way, example:

`havanbava`, I want the result as `avanava`, but my program gives me `ava`. How to fix this.

```
static void printSubStr(String str, int low, int high) {
    System.out.println(str.substring(low, high + 1));
}

static int longestPalindrome(String str) {
    int maxLength = 1; // The result (length of LPS)

    int start = 0;
    int len = str.length();

    int low, high;

    for (int i = 1; i < len; ++i) {
        low = i - 1;
        high = i;
        while (low >= 0 && high < len && str.charAt(low) == str.charAt(high)) {
            if (high - low + 1 > maxLength) {
                start = low;
                maxLength = high - low + 1;
            }
            --low;
            ++high;
        }

        low = i - 1;
        high = i + 1;
        while (low >= 0 && high < len && str.charAt(low) == str.charAt(high)) {
            if (high - low + 1 > maxLength) {
                start = low;
                maxLength = high - low + 1;
            }
            --low;
            ++high;
        }
    }

    System.out.print("Longest palindrome substring is: ");
    printSubStr(str, start, start + maxLength - 1);

    return maxLength;
}
```

Comment: "havanbava, I want the result as avanava" where did the b go?

Comment: `avanava` is not a substring of `havanbava`

Comment: I just need longest palindrome, it need not be substring, I can remove any character or multiple characters to compare. Just need to maintain the sequence.

Comment: A) that is not how palindromes are defined. A palindrome is "forward is same as backward" B) if you really want to have "XblaYblubZfooYbarX" to result in XYZYX, then you have a lot more to do. Because then we talk about walking that whole tree of possibilities of leaving out any particular substring. Then you talk a **huge** search tree, and DFS or BFS search strategies. Honestly, if I were you, I would stay with the exact definition of palindrome and not go for your much much more complicated variant.

Comment: @AndyTurner Question says "longest subsequence", not "longest substring", and `avanava` *is* a [subsequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subsequence) of `havanbava`.

Comment: @GhostCat Actually, the result for `XblaYblubZfooYbarX` would be one of `[XbYblbYbX, XbYbubYbX, XaYblbYaX, XaYbubYaX]`

Comment: See, it is so easy to get that wrong :-)

Comment: @user3181365, I updated my answer with more complete explanation of the idea from a dynamic programming point of view. I hope it is useful.

Answer (score 2):

Consider that there are two different longest palindrome subsequences (*avanava* and *avabava*) you can find all subsequences iteratively and then check if they are palindrome.
I use a Map to save all palindrome subsequences and their length and then loop through the map to select the longest.
This solution takes only the first longest ((*avanava*):

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Palindrome {
    // set to store all the subsequences
    static Map<String, Integer> subsequences = new HashMap<>();


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        subsequence("havanbava");

        //storing the higher key/value
        Map.Entry<String, Integer> maxEntry = null;

        for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : subsequences.entrySet())
        {
            if (maxEntry == null || entry.getValue().compareTo(maxEntry.getValue()) > 0)
            {
                maxEntry = entry;
            }
        }

        System.out.println(maxEntry.getKey());

    }

    static boolean isPalindrome(String str) {
         int n = str.length();
          for (int i = 0; i < (n/2); ++i) {
             if (str.charAt(i) != str.charAt(n - i - 1)) {
                 return false;
             }
          }

          return true;
    }


    static void subsequence(String str)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {


            for (int j = str.length(); j > i; j--) {
                String sub_str = str.substring(i, j);

                if (!subsequences.containsKey(sub_str)
                        && isPalindrome(sub_str))
                    subsequences.put(sub_str,sub_str.length());

                for (int k = 1; k < sub_str.length() - 1; k++) {
                    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(sub_str);

                    sb.deleteCharAt(k);

                    subsequence(sb.toString());
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Consider also that the iterative solution is resource-consuming, then for long strings it needs some big improvements.

This is a possible solution if you want **all** the longest subsequences (of the same length):

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Palindrome {
    // set to store all the subsequences
    static Map<String, Integer> subsequences = new HashMap<>();


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        subsequence("havanbava");

        //storing the higher key/value
        Map<String, Integer> maxEntries = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

        for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : subsequences.entrySet())
        {
            if (maxEntries.isEmpty()){
                maxEntries.put(entry.getKey(),entry.getValue());
            }else if(entry.getValue().compareTo( maxEntries.entrySet().iterator().next().getValue() ) == 0)
            {
                maxEntries.put(entry.getKey(),entry.getValue());
            }else if( entry.getValue().compareTo(maxEntries.entrySet().iterator().next().getValue()) > 0){
                maxEntries.clear();
                maxEntries.put(entry.getKey(),entry.getValue());
            }
        }
        for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> maxEntry : maxEntries.entrySet())
            System.out.println(maxEntry.getKey());

    }

    static boolean isPalindrome(String str) {
         int n = str.length();
          for (int i = 0; i < (n/2); ++i) {
             if (str.charAt(i) != str.charAt(n - i - 1)) {
                 return false;
             }
          }

          return true;
    }


    static void subsequence(String str)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {


            for (int j = str.length(); j > i; j--) {
                String sub_str = str.substring(i, j);

                if (!subsequences.containsKey(sub_str)
                        && isPalindrome(sub_str))
                    subsequences.put(sub_str,sub_str.length());

                for (int k = 1; k < sub_str.length() - 1; k++) {
                    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(sub_str);

                    sb.deleteCharAt(k);

                    subsequence(sb.toString());
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Тhis is a typical [dynamic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming) problem. You can find the length of the **longest palindrome subsequence**(LPS) in `O(n^2)` time. You should construct a memoization matrix like this:

```
     0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 -> indexes
     h a v a n b a v a -> input string
0 h  1 1 1 3 3 3 3 5 7 -> max_len = 7 -> a v a b a v a
1 a  0 1 1 3 3 3 3 5 7 
2 v  0 0 1 1 1 1 3 5 5 
3 a  0 0 0 1 1 1 3 3 3 
4 n  0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 3 
5 b  0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 3 
6 a  0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 3 
7 v  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 
8 a  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
```

The idea is to construct a matrix such that `matrix[i][j]`(0 <= i,j <= len) is equal to the LPS from i-th index to j-th index of the input.

If the LPS between `i`-th and `j`-th index (`i<=j`) is `LPS(i, j)` has length `L`:

- For `L=1` we have:
  `LPS(0,0) = LPS(1,1) = ... = LPS(8,8) = 1`
- For `L=2`: `LPS(0,1) = LPS(1,2) = ... = LPS(7,8) = 1` (if `input[i]=input[i+1]`, `LPS(i,i+1)=2`, i.e `aa` or `bb` but we do not have such case)
- For `L=3` we have:

  - `LPS(0,2) = max(LPS(0,1), LPS(1,2)) = max(1, 1) = 1`
  - `LPS(1,3) = LPS(1,1) + 2 = 3`
  - ...

More examples:

```
LPS(0,4) = max(LPS(0,3), LPS(1,4))=max(3,2) = 3
LPS(2,7) = LPS(3,6) + 2 = 3 + 2 = 5
```

So the rule is:

```
if input[i] != input[j]
    LPS(i,j) = max(LPS(i,j-1), LPS(i+1,j))
else
    LPS(i,j) = LPS(i+1,j-1) + 2
```

You can find a brilliant explanation of LPS [here](https://youtu.be/_nCsPn7_OgI). This guy explains really well and I strongly recommend his dynamic programming playlist. Of course the problem can be done with recursive solution(like every DP problem) but here I suggest an example DP solution:

```
public static String findLPS(String input) {
    int len = input.length();

    // initializes a diagonal matrix
    int[][] matrix = new int[len][len];
    for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
        matrix[i][i] = 1;
    }

    // finds the length of the longest palindrome subsequence
    for (int jj = 1; jj < len; jj++) {
        int i = 0;
        int j = jj;
        while (i < len && j < len) {
            if (input.charAt(i) == input.charAt(j)) {
                matrix[i][j] = matrix[i + 1][j - 1] + 2;
            } else {
                matrix[i][j] = Math.max(matrix[i + 1][j], matrix[i][j - 1]);
            }
            i++; j++;
        }
    }

    // reconstruct the solution from the matrix
    char[] path = new char[len];
    int i = 0;
    int j = len - 1;

    if (matrix[i][j] == 1) {
        return input.charAt(0) + "";
    }

    while (matrix[i][j] != 0) {
        if (matrix[i][j] == matrix[i + 1][j]) {
            i += 1;
        } else if (matrix[i][j] == matrix[i][j - 1]) {
            j -= 1;
        } else {
            path[i] = input.charAt(i);
            path[j] = input.charAt(j);
            i++; j--;
        }
    }

    String solution = "";
    for (int k = 0; k < len; k++) {
        if(path[k] != 0) {
            solution += path[k];
        }
    }

    return solution;
}
```